# How to compare dataframe column to another dataframe column inplace in pyspark?

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, col

```py
# DataframeA and DataframeB match:
DataframeA:
col: Name "Ali", "Bilal", "Ahsan"

DataframeB:
col: Name "Ali", "Bilal", "Ahsan"

# DataframeC and DataframeD DO NOT match:  
DataframeC:
col: Name "Ali", "Ahsan", "Bilal"

DataframeD:
col: Name "Ali", "Bilal", "Ahsan"
```

I want to match column values in place, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the issue then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below Scala code as a reference and translate it into python. Update `val check` line as per your `dataframe`  name.

```
    scala> val w = Window.orderBy(lit(1))
    scala> val check  = dfA.withColumn("rn", row_number.over(w)).alias("A").join(dfB.withColumn("rn", row_number.over(w)).alias("B"), List("rn"),"left").withColumn("check", when(col("A.name") === col("B.name"), lit("match")).otherwise(lit("not match"))).select("check").distinct.count

    scala> if (check == 1){
     | println("matched")} else (println("not matched"))
```

Answer (score 0):

use `set` for comparison in python.

```
DataframeC.columns
-> ["Ali", "Ahsan", "Bilal"]
DataframeD.columns
-> ["Ali", "Bilal", "Ahsan"]

DataframeC.columns == DataframeD.columns
-> False

set(DataframeC.columns) == set(DataframeD.columns)
-> True
```